# Problems with disabling responsive grid in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, adaptive-design

I need to disable responsive layout in Bootstrap, but I face some problems.

I replaced meta tag with:

```
content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"
```

And replaced the grid initialization in container with this:

```
.container {
  .container-fixed();

  @media (min-width: 200px) {
    width: @container-lg;
  }

  @media (min-width: @screen-xs-min) {
    width: @container-lg;
  }

  @media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) {
    width: @container-lg;
  }
  @media (min-width: @screen-md-min) {
    width: @container-lg;
  }
  @media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) {
    width: @container-lg;
  }

  // min-width: 980px !important;
}
```

But I see some bugs in small display resolution in my code:
http://www.playground.obuh.by/

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2):

From [Bootstrap's Documentation on Disabling Responsiveness](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive)

> 1. Omit the viewport `<meta>` mentioned in the CSS docs
> 2. Override the `width` on the `.container` for each grid tier with a single width, for example width: `970px !important;` Be sure that this comes after the default Bootstrap CSS. You can optionally avoid the !important with media queries or some selector-fu.
> 3. If using navbars, remove all navbar collapsing and expanding behavior.
> 4. For grid layouts, use `.col-xs-*` classes in addition to, or in place of, the medium/large ones. Don't worry, the extra-small device grid scales to all resolutions.

Particularly, pay attention to #4.  If you only use `col-xs`, you can still use the grid layout, but won't see changes on different screen sizes.

Comment: Thanks. But how can I fix this bug for any content (excluding **.navbar**): [http://joxi.ru/LRG0UxjKTJBeH_r380E](http://joxi.ru/LRG0UxjKTJBeH_r380E)?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you're pointing to in that screenshot.  Perhaps you can ask a new question with the relevant code to reproduce it.